# async/await + try/catch not working as spected when using a .then() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project using react, and i need to redirect to a logged in page if register is successful, so I added a state called redirect, empty when you access the register form that I need to set so the page can redirect, since I use a handler, this is the relevant component code:

```
    class Registro extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                email: "",
                password: "",
                passwordConfirm: "",
                userName: "",
                redirect: "",
            };
        }
    handleRedirect = () => {
        this.setState({ redirect: "/aplicacion" });
        console.log(this.state);
    }
  render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Navigate to={this.state.redirect} />
          }
        
        return (
          <button id="submit" className="btn btn-outline-accesible col-3 m-2 mt-3" 
                 onClick={() => {
                 registerWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.userName, this.state.email, this.state.password).then(
                      handleRedirect() 
                 )}}>Acceder</button>
```

And the register with email and password is this function:

```
    const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
    try {
        console.log(name, email, password)
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = res.user;
      await setDoc(doc(db, "users", email), {
        email: email,
        nombre: name,
        pass: password
      });
      alert("Registro completado con éxito")
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };
```

The expected outcome is that if the register is successful, the page reloads and you can go on your merry way, but if there's an error, the page won't load and the error will be alerted to the user. What is happening is that in the case there's an error, the page redirects you and then shows you an alert with the error data.

Thanks for reading and pondering this with me.

Comment: `.then(handleRedirect())` doesn't work at all. I suppose your actual code is `.then(this.handleRedirect)` (passing the function instead of calling it)?

Comment: Your code catches the error, handles it by alerting, and then proceeds to do the redirect. This is expected. Place the `handleRedirect` call inside the function instead of in a `.then()` call, and then put it *inside* the `try` block not after the `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the idea beneath mixing approach?

This should work

```
class Registro extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Navigate to={this.state.redirect} />;
    }

    return (
      <button
        id="submit"
        className="btn btn-outline-accesible col-3 m-2 mt-3"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        Acceder
      </button>
    );
  }

  handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      await registerWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.state.userName,
        this.state.email,
        this.state.password
      );
      handleRedirect();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };
}

const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  console.log(name, email, password);
  const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  const user = res.user;
  await setDoc(doc(db, "users", email), {
    email: email,
    nombre: name,
    pass: password,
  });
  alert("Registro completado con éxito");
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Please note that `registerWithEmailAndPassword` also updated to support correct error handling according to the request

Comment: This is missing the error handling though

Comment: It's handled in the original  `registerWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: I'm not sure i'm implementing it right, but now it trhows the error and then redirects me.

Comment: Am I right you don't want the redirect in case of error? @PedroMontesinosNavarro

Comment: Please check the update @PedroMontesinosNavarro

Comment: @Drag13 Thanks for the update. Yeah, you can't use the original `registerWithEmailAndPassword`…

Comment: If there is an error I don't want the page to leave the registration form, I want to stay there so the registree can fix the errors in the form

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, now I got the point. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `registerWithEmailAndPassword` function is *async*, so it returns a *Promise*. In this function, you call another async function, and you wait for its response. You are catching the exceptions thrown by `setDoc`. So your `registerWithEmailAndPassword`  always resolves. What you can do is :

- Return something if the function succeeds
- Return a rejected Promise in case of error

```js
const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
    try {
        console.log(name, email, password)
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = res.user;
      await setDoc(doc(db, "users", email), {
        email: email,
        nombre: name,
        pass: password
      });
      alert("Registro completado con éxito")
      return true
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
      return Promise.reject(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this solution too and it was valid. Thanks a lot man.